# Freebsd: pkg audit spread out in time over different servers

Tags: freebsd, vulnerabilities

We have several [Freebsd](https://freebsd.org) servers, where we check daily for vulnerabilities with `pkg audit`.

**Question:** Very often, the same vulnerability is reported in some servers only, and then in some others the next day. The question is: **why is that?**

**More info:**

**1.** The servers are mostly identical: same version, same installed software and doing the same duties.

**2.** I've tried logging in to the servers which did not report the vulnerability:

1. `portsnap fetch update` then `pkg audit` give `0 problem(s) in the installed packages found.`
2. `portmaster <packagename>` tries to reinstall the vulnerable package rather than upgrade it.

**3.** `uname -a` on two different servers:

```
FreeBSD host1.domain.com 10.3-RELEASE-p17 FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p17 #14: Wed Apr 12 08:59:21 CEST 2017     admin@host1.domain.com:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/MYKERNEL  i386
FreeBSD host2.domain.org 10.3-RELEASE-p17 FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p17 #9: Fri Feb 24 13:30:09 CET 2017     root@host2.domain.3b:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/MYKERNEL  i386
```

**4.** In all cases, `portsnap fetch update` downloads form the same mirror:

```
Fetching snapshot tag from ec2-eu-west-1.portsnap.freebsd.org
```

**5.** Example of vulnerabilities found by `pkg audit`:

```
curl-7.54.1 is vulnerable:
cURL -- multiple vulnerabilities
CVE: CVE-2017-1000101
CVE: CVE-2017-1000100
CVE: CVE-2017-1000099
WWW: https://vuxml.FreeBSD.org/freebsd/69cfa386-7cd0-11e7-867f-b499baebfeaf.html

sqlite3-3.19.3_1 is vulnerable:
sqlite3 -- heap-buffer overflow
CVE: CVE-2017-10989
WWW: https://vuxml.FreeBSD.org/freebsd/9245681c-7c3c-11e7-b5af-a4badb2f4699.html
```

**6.** All servers are in the same location and share the same *direct* Internet connection. No proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you confirm that you are using `pkg audit -F`:

```
 -F, --fetch
        Fetch the database before checking.
```

Beside that, if servers are not in the same locations, it's also possible that:

- some servers are using a proxy caching the database file
- servers are not using the same VulnXML mirror (vuxml.freebsd.org is automatically redirected to closest mirror)

Comment: I bet you mean `pkg audit -F`. I'll try adding the `-F` switch and see what happens. All servers are in the same location and share the same Internet connection without using a proxy.

Comment: It seems this is it: running `pkg audit -F` against all servers helped discover an as of yet unreported vulnerability that had been patched everywhere else but on that server.

Comment: `pkg audit -F` indeed, answer fixed :)